# Android JUnit Test: have some skipped internal methods

Tags: android, methods, junit, testcase, android-testing

I started looking into the [Android JUnit Testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html), done some researches on the Internet, and enough trials on Eclipse with ADT.

i notice if a test case (i.e. an user-defined method in the [`junit.framework.TestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestCase.html) subclass, or specifically, my subclass entends [`android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T extends android.app.Activity>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html), according to the guide in the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html)) is non-public (no matter private or /*package*/), JUnit will give me some errors.

**So, how can i have some non-test-case (internal) methods in the Android JUnit testing?**

i need those methods for me to help testing the test cases.

As i found from the Internet, Android Junit test is a bit different from the original JUnit test, as some annotations like `@Before` and `@After` are not supported in Android. But i guess the way of including non-test-case methods are still the same.

Note: Please noted that i am **not** going to test some private methods in a class, as many people have been asking.

Thanks for any helps :-)

Comment: You should be able to mark methods as non-test-cases with the annotation `@Suppress`, however I'm not sure if that works with private methods.

Comment: Thanks @dst! `@Suppress` is exactly the thing i was looking for! I have tested it works for public methods, with/without parameters. For /\*package\*/ and protected methods, JUnit will still give errors. But this is not a big deal - just keep them public. In addition, i have tested we can define inner classes. We don't need any annotations to mask them. JUnit won't touch them :-)

Comment: i am not sure with the standard JUnit. But i have just found by trials that the Android JUnit test cases (method names) need to start with "test...()" and with zero parameters. After digging into the source codes, i have verified this behaviour in [android.test.TestRunner](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/donut-release/test-runner/android/test/TestRunner.java) line 638 : `m.getName().startsWith("test") && m.getReturnType() == void.class && m.getParameterTypes().length == 0`. Is this a normal JUnit standard, or an Android added feature?

Comment: In regular JUnit you mark tests with the `@Test` annotation, parameters are only supported on JUnit 4+ (`@RunWith`).